# How to solve this definite integral $ \int_0 ^a \sqrt {9-x^2} \ dx $ without using trigonometric substitution

Tags: definite-integrals, circles, pi

> For what value(s) of $a$ is $$ \int_0 ^a \sqrt {9-x^2} \  dx = \pi \ \text{ ?} $$

I solved this question by using integral substitution, but I was told that it is better to obtain this solution by using the graphichal method.

I tried it, but I wasn't able to have any useful insight.

When I did it using trignomteric substituton, I ended up with the following equation for $a$, which I wasn't sure how to simplify (hence I need for a better method):

> $$ \Rightarrow \arcsin \left(\frac{a}{3}\right) + \frac {1}{2} \sin \left[ 2 \arcsin \left(\frac{a}{3} \right) \right] =  \frac {2}{9} \pi $$

Comment: What value(s) have you got for $a$?

Comment: $a$ would have only one value $ 1.07... $

Comment: @Daniel Wang You can make graph of $\displaystyle y =  \arcsin (\frac{a}{3}) $ and $ \displaystyle  y = \frac {2}{9} \pi - \frac {a \sqrt {9 - a^2} }{18} $ because $\displaystyle \frac {1}{2} \sin [ 2 \arcsin (\frac {a}{3}) ]$ can be further simplified.

Comment: But how would that help solve for a though?

Comment: If $y = \sqrt{9-x^2}$ then $y^2 = 9-x^2,$ so $y^2+x^2= 3^2.$ That is the equation of a circle whose center is $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and whose radius is $3.$

If $y^2 + x^2 = 3^2$ then $y = \pm\sqrt{9-x^2},$ and you've only got $\text{“}+\text{''}$ and not $\text{“}-\text{''},$ so the graph of $y= \sqrt{9-x^2}$ is the top half of the circle.

If you integrate from $0$ to $3$ you get the area of the part of the circle that is in the first quadrant, which is $1/4$ of the circle, so it's $\pi r^2/4= \pi\cdot9/4.$

Comment: $\ldots\,$so if you had had $y= \sqrt{4-x^2},$ then integrating from $0$ to $2$ would have given you exactly $\pi.$

Comment: Use the formula for the sine of twice the angle.

Comment: You could try but the problem is not the angle, it's x.

Comment: I tried before but doesn't work when solving the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Graphically, the integral 
$$ \int_0 ^a \sqrt {9-x^2} \  dx = \pi $$

represents the shaded area in the diagram, which is the area sum of the circle sector of angle $x$ and the right triangle of base length $a=r\sin x$, i.e.

$$\pi = \frac12 x r^2 + \frac 12 r^2\sin x\cos x$$

where $r=3$ is the radius of the circle. Rewrite the equation as,

$$x + \frac12\sin 2x = \frac{2\pi}9$$

which does not have a close form solution and can only be solved numerically. But, a decent approximation can be obtained with $\sin 2x \approx 2x$ to obtain $x = \frac\pi9$. Thus, $a = 3\sin \frac\pi9 = 1.03$, compared with exact numerical result $1.07$

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote it, considering the equation$$\arcsin \left(\frac{a}{3}\right) + \frac {1}{2} \sin \left[ 2 \arcsin \left(\frac{a}{3} \right) \right] =k \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=  \frac {2\pi}{9} $$ Composing  Taylor series around $a=0$, the lhs is
$$\frac{2 a}{3}-\frac{a^3}{81}-\frac{a^5}{4860}-\frac{a^7}{122472}+O\left(a^9\right)$$ Using series reversion
$$a=\frac{3 k}{2}+\frac{k^3}{16}+\frac{13 k^5}{1280}+\frac{493
   k^7}{215040}+O\left(k^9\right)$$

Plugging this result into the original equation and expanding again around $k=0$ gives for the lhs
$$k-\frac{37369 }{92897280}k^9+O\left(k^{11}\right)$$
Using $k=\frac {2\pi}{9}$, this gives $a=1.07033$ while the exact solution is
                                      $a=1.07036$